# Multisite Tables the same as Single Install?

Tags: multisite, mysql

Are the tables created for each individual site/blog on Multisite the same as single? Can I do an SQL dump for each MS table and import it to a single install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're some [special tables <sup>Codex Link</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Multisite_Table_Overview) in Multisite.

In short: No you can't. But you can degrade to a single site install and then import them there. If in doubt, simply add a new local multisite install, import the posts there, downgrade to single site and then export/import again.